# Make TabBarView take up all remaining space

Tags: flutter, tabs, widget, constraints

New to Flutter and can't figure out how to put size constraints on my UI so nothing overflows. Trying to make a little bit different UI with tabs, where I have some components above the tab bar. Basically I want something like this:

```
--------------------
|     Container    |
--------------------
|      TabBar      |
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|    TabBarView    |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
|     Container    |
--------------------
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to make the TabBarView take up the remaining space. My code example wont even run, just gives me an error like this:

I/flutter ( 3875): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3875): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 3875): Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 3875): Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match
I/flutter ( 3875): their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of
I/flutter ( 3875): vertical space in which to expand.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
      Tab(text: 'TAB 1'),
      Tab(text: 'TAB 2'),
      Tab(text: 'TAB 3'),
    ];

    Widget topBar = Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("TEXT 1"),
            Text("TEXT 2"),
            Text("TEXT 3"),
          ],
        ));

    Widget bottomBar = Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(child: Text("Cancel")),
        RaisedButton(child: Text("OK")),
      ],
    );

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Test"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            topBar,
            TabBar(
              tabs: myTabs,
            ),
            TabBarView(
              children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(tab.text)
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: bottomBar,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put TabBarView inside `Expanded` widget